# Delete images programmatically by accessing their tag

Tags: ios, swift

**Swift 3 / Xcode 8.3.3**

When I click on the screen, an image appears **(code 1)** at the place of the click (if I click 5 times, 5 images appear) and each image has a tag. Now I would like to delete the images one by one at each click on a button **(code 2)** but only the last image is deleted...

I did a lot of research but none of the results worked for me.

**code 1:**

```
        var imageView : UIImageView!
        var lstTagImage: [Int] = []
        var concatenateInt: String = ""
        var lstPoint: [Point] = []

        concatenateInt = "\(Int(i))\(Int(j))"
        lstPoint.append(Point(x: i, y: j, weigth: weigthChip))

        imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: X,
                                              y: Y,
                                              width: 20, height: 20));

        imageView.tag = Int(concatenateInt)!
        lstTagImage.append(Int(concatenateInt)!)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageString)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

**code 2:**

```
@IBAction func undoButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (lstPoint.count != 0){
        lstPoint.remove(at: lstPoint.count - 1)
        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        print("list empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `viewWithTag` to retreive the last tag, remove that tag from the array and remove the image from its superview.

```
if lstPoint.count != 0,
    let lastTag = lstTagImage.last {
    lstPoint.remove(at: lstPoint.count - 1)
    lstTagImage.removeLast()

    let imageView = view.viewWithTag(lastTag)
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate, more elegant approach would be something like this:

```
let addedImages = [UIImageView]()

// When adding an image to the view
addedImages.append(imageView)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Then it's easy to delete.

```
// When deleting image from view
if let imageView = addedImages.last {
    imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    addedImages.removeLast()
}
```